# Is $e^{(2i\ln b)}=(e^{\ln b})^{2i}=b^{2i}$ where $b$ is a real positive number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here, $b$ is a positive real number. Does the equalities below holds true? The complex exponential is quite messy.

$$e^{(2i\ln b)}=(e^{\ln b})^{2i}=b^{2i}$$

I believe there is some multiple of $2i\pi$ missing somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that is how we define by exponentiation for complex exponents.  The thing is by the time we've gotten to these level there's really no longer any point in expressing anything in a base other than $e$ so the issue almost never comes up.

Comment: Well $e^{2i\ln b} = e^{2i\ln b + 2k\pi i}$ so $b^{\theta i} = b^{(\theta + \frac {2k\pi}{\ln b})i}$ and $b^z$ will have a period of $\frac {2\pi}{\ln b}i$ and ... I dont know why I've never seen that before but it seems fairly straightforward and banal.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally fine. There is nothing missing.

I think you meant something like

$\ln(-a) = (2n+1)*\pi*i +\ln(a)$

for every integer n.